# data reactive filtering using multiple input in R Shiny

Tags: r, filter, shiny, leaflet, reactive

I'm developping a shiny app diplaying a leaflet map. I'm facing the pretty same situation than this topic :
[Change Leaflet Map Dynamically based on Multiple Reactive expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070730/change-leaflet-map-dynamically-based-on-multiple-reactive-expressions)

I tried to subset the dataframe according to multiple input selection in order to create a dynamic map. But I didn't succeed to deal with the vector lenght error "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".
This was fixed in the other topic with changing the "==" operator by "%in%", but not in my case.

My code :

```
all_year <- sort(unique(sample_testsf$annee))
all_area <- sort(unique(sample_testsf$nomzone))

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("AgriPAG"),
    sidebarLayout(
        position = "right",
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Map", leafletOutput('mymap',width = "100%", height = 1000))
            )
        ),
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(
                inputId = "year",
                label = "Select a year to display",
                choices = all_year,
                selected = NULL,
                multiple = TRUE,
                selectize = FALSE
            ),
            selectInput(
                inputId = "area",
                label = "Select a district",
                choices = all_area,
                selected = NULL,
                multiple = TRUE,
                selectize = FALSE
            )
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input,output){

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(data = sample_testsf) %>%
                addTiles() %>%
                setView(lng=-52.3333300, lat=4.9333300 , zoom=5)
    })

    selectedData <- reactive({
        req(input$year)
        req(input$area)
        sample_testsf %>% 
            dplyr::filter(all_year %in% input$year & all_area %in% input$area
            )
    })

    observe({
        leafletProxy("mymap", data = selectedData()) %>%
            clearShapes() %>%
            addPolygons(weight=2, col="black", opacity=0.5) 
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I actually understand why this problem is occuring  ([Why do I get "warning longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865095/why-do-i-get-warning-longer-object-length-is-not-a-multiple-of-shorter-object-l)) and I guess I should use the recycling function but I do not know how to set it up. Anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake, I was calling for the input choice list instead of the selected input in the reactive function. The solution :

```
selectedData <- reactive({
    req(input$year)
    req(input$area)
    sample_testsf %>% 
        dplyr::filter(annee %in% input$year & nomzone%in% input$area
        )
})
```